# Show image name inside the image field in Django forms

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have this edit or update form in which I want to display only the image name in the form for a better user experience so that the user could know which image he has uploaded while creating the data.
I am storing the image name in the model as well,but i want to display the image name inside the image field.
forms.py

```
class MenuCategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField(allow_empty_file=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = MenuCategory
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'menu_options']
```

view

```
def menu_category_update(request, id):
    item = MenuCategory.objects.get(id=id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MenuCategoryForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=item)

        if form.is_valid():
            if request.FILES['image']:
                image = request.FILES['image']
                image_url = upload_image(image, 'menu_category', image.name)
                obj = form.save(commit=False)
                obj.image_url = image_url
                form.save()

            else:
                form.save()
            return redirect('menu-category')

    else:
        form = MenuCategoryForm(instance=item)

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'item': item
    }
    return render(request, 'menu/menu_category_update.html', context)
```

Template

```
{% extends 'partials/base.html' %} {% load crispy_forms_filters %} {% load
crispy_forms_tags %}
<!-- {% block title %}Menu category {% endblock %} -->
{% block content %}
<div class="container edit-form-flex">
  <div class="row Edit-form-box">
    <div class="form-inner-box bg-white">
      <div class="heading-editing">
        <h3>Edit menu category</h3>
      </div>

      <form method="POST" class="add-new-form edit-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %} {{ form|crispy }}

        <div class="update-buttons-container">
          <button class="btn btn-info1" type="submit" value="Update">
            Update
          </button>
          <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{% url 'menu-category' %}"
            >Cancel</a
          >
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Show your `menu_category_update.html`

Comment: @Lewis I have updated the question.Please check

Answer (score 0):

Well in other to get the name of the image in your form you will be better off in using a form initial like so:

```
def menu_category_update(request,id):
    item = MenuCategory.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MenuCategoryForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=item)
        if form.is_valid:
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
           # obj.username = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('menu-category')
        else:
            form = MenuCategoryForm(
                initial={'image':item.image,
                                'name':item.name,
                                  'description':iteem.description,
})# this are the fields that we want to show in the form 
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'item': item
    }
    return render(request, 'menu/menu_category_update.html', context)
```

In your form html you will apply the form initial to the field that you want to show in your form, by doing something like this: form.initial.name As i have illustrated below :

```
{% extends 'partials/base.html' %} {% load crispy_forms_filters %} {% load
crispy_forms_tags %}
<!-- {% block title %}Menu category {% endblock %} -->
{% block content %}
<div class="container edit-form-flex">
  <div class="row Edit-form-box">
    <div class="form-inner-box bg-white">
      <div class="heading-editing">
        <h3>Edit menu category</h3>
      </div>

      <form method="POST" class="add-new-form edit-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %} 
     <label> Image name </label>
       {{form.initial.name}}
    <label> Description </label>
        {{ form.initial.description }}
        <label> Image </label>     
       {{ form.initial.image }}
        <div class="update-buttons-container">
          <button class="btn btn-info1" type="submit" value="Update">
            Update
          </button>
          <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{% url 'menu-category' %}"
            >Cancel</a
          >
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: 'str' object has no attribute 'field' getting this error

Comment: I am suspecting the error is coming from this lines image_url = upload_image(image, 'menu_category', image.name)  and this line  obj.image_url = image_url delete both lines and try runing your codes again !

Comment: I edited my view in the answer, please copy it and use it , it would work now without any problem!

Comment: can you look into this question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71014531/show-initial-data-to-the-image-field-in-django-forms

Comment: mark if it solve your problem and then i will work on that too!

Comment: No it did not resolve the issue

Comment: what is the error this time and can  you let me knw ?

Comment: No error, it is not displaying any field its just an empty form

Comment: please look into the above question

Comment: Since my solution didn't work, i guess there's no need working on that one!

Comment: yes, that's why I have opted for another approach please look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71014531/show-initial-data-to-the-image-field-in-django-forms

Comment: I figured your form Html needed updating too and so i edited it and you should copy and try it! hopefully it would work this time around!

Comment: it has created a new field and displaying that in it, but I need the name inside an existing field

Comment: I have made the correction, tell me the other fields you would want in the form?

Comment: Please make sure you put  the field that you would want in the form in the form initial in views.py as i have added the description to the views and then to the form HTML.

Comment: Did it work this time around ?

Comment: You are not getting the question, I have two fields Image and Image name now I want to show the image name inside the image field, not on the separate field

Comment: Well its the best i could come up with maybe someone will have a better solution than mine,. Do mean to merge both field into one field ? at least vote my solution to keep me motivated lol!

Comment: Can you help me in one more thing?

Comment: what could that possibly be ?

Comment: can you create a chat box? where we can chat?

Comment: or you can give me your LinkedIn or any other social media profile

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241816/discussion-between-abu-godda-and-the-knight).