# Show initial data to the image field in Django forms

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have this custom image field I want to show the initial to its field, like the name of the image, etc.
This method is not working only on the image field like if I set initial to the name field it is working but not on the image or file field
form.py

```
class MenuCategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField(allow_empty_file=True, required=False)

    def __init__(self, exp=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MenuCategoryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if exp:
            self.fields['image'].initial = exp

    class Meta:
        model = MenuCategory
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'menu_options']
```

view.py

```
form = MenuCategoryForm(exp="test.jpg")
```

Template

```
<form method="POST" class="add-new-form edit-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %} {{ form|crispy }}
```

Comment: You can only work a form initial from the views.py and not from the forms.py  unless  you are using some magic to do that!

Comment: I have tried this solution, this is working on all other fields but not on the image

Comment: if i tried to setup the initial for the name it is working , but not for the image field

Comment: Okay i guess you would need to read docs to help you better understand how to go about it here is the link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/api/#initial-form-values

Comment: Add the image field to your meta class  for form like so : fields = ['name', 'description', 'image','menu_options']

Comment: Tried, but did not work